# Command pattern, EF Core, type casting and MS DI

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, casting, command-pattern, microsoft-extensions-di

How to put together this approches correctly?

Today I'm struggling with emplementing domain events, or something that looks like it.
Let's say, I've got  this (not a real code):

```cs
public abstract class ActionDataBase 
{ 
    int Id {get; set;} 
}

public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : ActionDataBase
{ 
    public Task HandleAsync<T>(T actionData) 
}
```

And then it turns into

```cs
public class SayHelloToJohnActionData : ActionDataBase
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } = "John" 
}

public class SayHelloToJohnActionHandler : ICommandHandler<SayHelloToJohnActionData>
{
    private SomeDeps _dep;

    public SayHelloToJohnActionHandler(SomeDeps dep) => _dep = dep;

    public Task HandleAsync(SayHelloToJohnActionData data)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {data.Name}!");
    }
}
```

Finally I register it as a service and then make an entity for a EF Core

```cs
public class LovelyThing
{
    public int LovelyThingId  { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ActionDataBase> GoodFriends { get; set; }
}
```

What's the point? I know this code smells and also lack of experience, but in my mind, I want to store all essential data for some action and I want to get dependecies for it from DI container. So the last step is

```cs
foreach(var goodFriend in GoodFriends)
    await _dispatcher.Dispatch(goodFriend);
```

Somewhere and then:

```cs
public ActionHandlerDispatcher : IActionHandlerDispatcher
{
    private ServiceProvider _sp;

    public ActionHandlerDispatcher(ServiceProvider sp) => _sp = sp;

    public Task DispatchAsync<T>(T actionData)
    {
        // WELL....
    }
}
```

I've got an option for a WELL

```cs
var generic = typeof(ICommandHandler<>) 
var argType = actionData.GetType(); 
var constructed = generic.MakeGenericType(argType) 
var handler = (ICommandHandler<T>) _provider.GetRequiredService(constructed); // type casting error, because T is an ActionDataBase
await handler.Handler(actionData);
```

My question is how can I deal with it? I know that Command Pattern and Domain Events looks different, but this approach, I guess, should be usefull for me. I am about to store derived types form ActionDataBase in TPH way, and also it looks very extenable. But type casting part confuses me a lot.

Seems like IConverter's `Convert.ChangeType` is not my thing

Comment: Is it because you want to avoid the reflection in `ActionHandlerDispatcher`? If so, you could register `ActionHandlerDispatcher` as an open generic type in the DI, and then resolve it with concrete, derived types of `ActionDataBase`. This does however require that you know the type at some point, when you use the open generic type of `ActionHandlerDispatcher`.

Comment: @Kristin I do want to avoid the part where I use Switch or any other explicit tool to determinate type at compile time because if I am gonna add a new ***ActionData and ***ActionHandler, I have to change explicit determination code part too. Is it even possible to store this type of Dtos in Db via parent type `ICollection<ActionDataBase> GoodFriends`  and then resolving with something? Because handlers need dependencies